# Ruby on Rails: Decompression (Zlib::Deflate) doesn't work after certain amount of time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zlib

I have a need to compress large chunk of text before saving it to the database and decompress it back once client requests it.

The method I am using right now seems to work fine when I insert new records using the Rails console and query for the newly inserted record right away. i.e., I can decompress the compressed description successfully.

But I am not able to decompress the compressed `description` for any of my other records added prior to this date. It is really confusing for me especially being a beginnner to the ROR world.

I am using MySQL as a database.

See my Model below to better understand it.

```
require "base64"

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :compress_description

  def desc
    unless description.blank?
      return decompress(description)
    end
  end

  private

  def compress_description
    unless description.blank?
      self.description = compress(description)
    end
  end

  def compress(text)
    Base64.encode64(Zlib::Deflate.new(nil, -Zlib::MAX_WBITS).deflate(text, Zlib::FINISH))
  end

  def decompress(text)
    Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS).inflate(Base64.decode64(text))
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly you are using this model. I tried this very same thing and it works just fine for me. I suspect that maybe you are using the description instead of the desc method when looking for the unencrypted string but I'd like to confirm if that is the case.

Comment: @user420504: No I am using `desc` And for me `desc` does work if I get the inserted records on the same day. But if I try to pull the same record after couple of days, it just gives me `junk`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok it's actually very easy to reproduce your problem. In rails console do the following

```
Video.create(:description => "This is a test")
Video.last.description
=> "C8nILFYAokSFktTiEgA=\n" 
Video.last.desc
=> "This is a test" 
Video.last.save #This update corrupts the description
Video.last.desc
=> "C8nILFYAokSFktTiEgA=\n"
```

The reason the corruption happens is because you are compressing an already compressed string

You should probably modify your class as follows and you should be fine

```
require 'base64'
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :compress_description
  after_find :decompress_description
  attr_accessor :uncompressed_description

  private

  def compress_description
    unless @uncompressed_description.blank?
    self.description = compress(@uncompressed_description)
    end
  end

  def decompress_description
    unless description.blank?
      @uncompressed_description = decompress(description)
    end
  end

  def compress(text)
    Base64.encode64(Zlib::Deflate.new(nil, -Zlib::MAX_WBITS).deflate(text, Zlib::FINISH))
  end

  def decompress(text)
    Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS).inflate(Base64.decode64(text))
  end
end
```

Now use your class as follows

```
Video.create(:uncompressed_description => "This is a test")
Video.last.description
=> "C8nILFYAokSFktTiEgA=\n" 
Video.last.uncompressed_description
=> "This is a test" 
Video.last.save
Video.last.uncompressed_description
=> "This is a test"
```